# Background centered for image < than the page and left when image > than the page

Tags: css

Is it possible in CSS to handle the position of a background image depending of the dimension of the browser page, or should I use javascript to handle that?

When the **image is bigger than the page** it should be aligned to the **left**

When the **image is smaller than the page** it should be aligned to the **center**

Answer (score 2):

Media queries - they change CSS styles dependent on browser size.

```
#img { 
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media 
screen and (max-device-width: 1000px), 
screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

  #img { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```